# removing new line from list with python

Tags: python

i have file
list.py with list:

```
my_list = ['1','2','3'],['1','2','3'],['1','2','3'],\n
```

in main.py i have:

```
import list

listM = []
listM = list.my_list
```

how can i remove all \n from listM?

i try it with

```
listM.replace("\n", "")
```

and

```
new_l = filter(lambda x:re.findall('^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$', x), listM)
```

but nothing working every time i get error list object has no atribute replace or somterhing that

Comment: error still exist if i change name.... tuple object has no atribute replace

Comment: `replace` is for str.

Comment: `my_list = ['1','2','3'],['1','2','3'],['1','2','3'],\n` is not valid python

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question, but I hope this might help you.

```py
import json

my_list = ['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3'], "\n"
dumped_list = json.dumps(my_list)
removed_list = json.loads(dumped_list.replace("\\n", ""))

print(list(filter(lambda x: x != "", removed_list)))
```

**OUtput:**

```
[['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3']]
```

Comment: my problem is that ... into my_list i write some values for example {'1', '2', '3'] with foo = open('path', 'a') foo.write(text...1,2.3.) and every time it write on new line...

Comment: Could you update your question with exact data? It could help us to guide you better

Comment: i only need write to file to the end of a line...not to new line only to the end of line is this possible?

Comment: Did you tried `with open("file.txt", "a") as file:`?. opening with `a` mode will let you write at the end of the file. is that what you need?

Comment: Maybe you should read lines and add data to each line and then write

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understand your question.

If `my_list` is a python object, it should be define as `['1','2','3'],['1','2','3'],['1','2','3'], '\n'`. If it is, try the following code

```
import list
listM = tuple(filter(lambda x: x != '\n', list.my_list))
```

On the other hand, if you want `my_list` define as text, its file extension should be .txt, and you have to read that file, then handle the string inside